# How can I find consecutively "occupied" elements in a C++ array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm creating a command line game that includes a 10 x 10 `char` array, represented like this:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 . . . . . . . . . .
1 . . . . . . . . . .
2 . . . . . . . . . .
3 . . . . . . . b . .
4 . . A B C . 1 2 3 .
5 . . . . . . . . . .
6 . . . . . . . . . .
7 . . . . . C c 3 . .
8 . . . . . . . . . .
9 . . . . . . . . . .
```

Each `.` represents an unoccupied spot on the board and the letters and numbers are pieces that have already been played. The numbers on the upper edge and left edge are just for reference.

In order to calculate points and ensure that pieces are played in the correct places, I'd like to create "sub-array" of consecutive pieces adjacent to the piece that has just been played. From the example above, if `B` had just been played, then that `char` array would contain `A`, `B`, and `C`.

I'm having a hard time finding the "starting" (left-most) and "ending" (right-most) pieces of this consecutive sub-array. Once I have those this is easy to solve. Obviously I could start at one end of the board and just add to an array any piece that's not `.`, but then I'd end up with all the pieces in that row, not just the ones adjacent to the piece that has just been played.

I've tried the following, but it still prints the wrong output (off by one on both sides):

```
void Board::createHorizontalRun(int row, int column) {
    int i = column;
    int j = column;

    while (array[row][i] != '.' && i >= 0 && i <= 9) {
        i--;
    }
    while (array[row][j] != '.' && j >= 0 && j <= 9) {
        j++;
    }
    cout << "run begins at " << i << endl;
    cout << "run ends at " << j << endl;
}
```

**How can I find the starting and ending locations of the consecutive pieces adjacent to the piece that has just been played?**

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for flood fill: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill. That is, unless you're only looking for a horizontal or vertical run one grid cell wide, in which case the problem is simpler.

Comment: Take out a piece of paper and a pen. Write down, using plain English, in short, logical sentences, a step by step process of implementing your algorithm. [After discussing your proposed logic with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), as soon as your rubber duck agrees that your logic is correct, simply take what you've written down and directly translate it into code. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Notice how your code successfully identifies "the first '.' adjacent to your run" in both directions, and that you know that the start position is never a '.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with after following Sam's advice:

```
vector<char> Board::getHorizontalRun(int row, int column) {
    int runStart = column;
    int runEnd = column;
    vector<char> horizontalRun;

    // find starting position of run
    while (true) {
        if (isInBounds(row, runStart - 1)) {
            if (array[row][runStart - 1] == '.') {
                break;
            } else {
                runStart--;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // find ending position of array
    while (true) {
        if (isInBounds(row, runEnd + 1)) {
            if (array[row][runEnd + 1] == '.') {
                break;
            } else {
                runEnd++;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Use start and end positions to populate vector
    for (int i = runStart; i <= runEnd; i++) {
        horizontalRun.push_back(array[row][i]);
    }

    return horizontalRun;
}
```